# Wacom Tablet in 13.04

Tags: dual-boot, wacom, graphics-tablet

I've been scanning the forums looking for a straight answer. I'm planning on buying a Wacom Intuos5 large for graphic design and art work but would like to know if Ubuntu has enough decent support for me to get full functionality out of my tablet. I wouldn't mind doing some heavy programming to get things working right, but as long as it is possible, and as long as there are enough resources for me to search through since I know 0 C(programming) or any other programming language for that matter, beyond PHP.

So, will my Tablet work perfectly in Ubuntu? or will I have to dual-boot? (really don't want to dual boot)

Answer (score 1):

Try this page: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139480&page=2

...it's a tad tecchy, but it boils down to the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xutils-dev libudev-dev
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom
cd xf86-input-wacom
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib
make
sudo make install
```

If you get these errors when you try the above:

```
No package 'xorg-server' found No package 'randrproto' found
```

....then do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxi-dev x11proto-input-dev xserver-xorg-dev tk8.4-dev tcl8.4-dev libncurses5-dev libx11-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev
```

& then go back into the xf86-input-wacom directory & re-do the

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib
```

command.

Followed by:

```
make
sudo make install
```

...and you should be all set to use your lovely Wacom tablet on Ubuntu 13.04

I've just done the above on a 64-bit machine with no problems (& the above will work on a 32 bit machine too).

Cheers,

Dez.

Comment: Woah thank you so much!
After doing some research, I opted for a Intuos4 since it seemed really similar spec-wise and I got it for only £200, 
It had better support on LibWacom as well, will this work for all Wacom tablets?

Answer (score 0):

My sister has one (dont know the models name) and she told me, when she came to visit me, that I couldnt use it on my computer, because I needed a special software to install first (she didnt bring the CD). Lets see, my computer might be different, I said. Plugged it in, and it worked right out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it works out of the box for basic tasks, but I want to know if it will be fully functional, will I be able to set preset buttons for other applications? will full pressure sensitivity be there? is the touch pad interface smooth, or buggy. Things of that nature, like I said, Hardcoding doesn't matter to me, I'll do it if that means that I can stick with Ubuntu, I love this OS so much, but my work DOES come first, and I can't work if my G-Tablet won't work.